# Exception Unhandled: System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, visual-studio-2019

Basically, it has been 3 days since I'm trying to resolve this issue. I'm coding a sort of Mail Client in C# - everything was working pretty much good, while I started getting this unhandled exception... I would like to post a code section, but I do not know exactly what it causing this problem. A good fact is that the project is pushed over [Github](https://github.com/Moltivie/Email-Management-Client/tree/deviation). Over internet it is said that maybe some variables used on some loops may cause the problem; I've already tried to edit some parts, but unluckily nothing worked...

Latest edit: 
Added a `Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton` over a `UserControl`. On click event, this happens:

```cs
MessageBox.Show(settingsControl.FLAG.ToString());
```

- I was testing if this would print me the `int FLAG` variable taken from another `UserControl` called `settingsControl`.

Every suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One way to learn more about errors like this in the field is to capture a memory dump when the error occurs using [Procdump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump).  To capture the memory error when it happens, use a command line like `procdump -e 1 -f OutOfMemoryException -w MyProgram.exe -ma C:\...PathGoesHere...\MyProgram-OutOfMemoryException.dmp`.  Once you have a dump file, use [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) to analyze it.  Or, if you have a project inside Visual Studio, launch the program and break on exceptions.

Comment: In recent versions of Visual Studio, you can attach to a dump file inside Visual Studio itself and see where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this method. I will let know whether it has worked or not.

Comment: @PaulWilliams Is dumping the file over Task Manager worth it?

Comment: Task Manager memory dumps give you a view of the process at that moment.  Procdump can capture the dump file when the error occurs.  Note that on a 64-bit system, Task Manager will generate good memory dumps for 64-bit processes only, and it will generate a corrupt dump file for 32-bit processes.  Procdump and Process Explorer (also from Microsoft Sysinternals) do not have this limitation.

Comment: Yeah, because I was watching a video showing the usage of Task Manager, but I have Process Explorer installed. Dumped it and analyzing in progress...